# nmap to read ports from a file

Tags: nmap

I found this question and tried the solution given (accepted)

[Can nmap take a list of ports to scan from a file?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128688/can-nmap-take-a-list-of-ports-to-scan-from-a-file)

However, it didn't really work as expected.

```
$ cat ports.list
21
22
23
25
$
```

Instead of scanning the ports in the file, nmap assume those ports as part of the host. See output below.

```
$ nmap 127.0.0.1 -vvv -p `cat ports.list`
Starting Nmap
Initiating Ping Scan at 10:50
Scanning 4 hosts [2 ports/host]
Completed Ping Scan at 10:50, 1.22s elapsed (4 total hosts)
Nmap scan report for 22 (0.0.0.22) [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for 23 (0.0.0.23) [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for 25 (0.0.0.25) [host down, received no-response]
Initiating Connect Scan at 10:50
Scanning localhost (127.0.0.1) [1 port]
Completed Connect Scan at 10:50, 0.00s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up, received conn-refused (0.000059s latency).
Scanned for 1s

PORT   STATE  SERVICE REASON
21/tcp closed ftp     conn-refused

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 4 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 1.28 seconds

$
```

Is it possible to take a list of ports to scan from a file?

Answer (score 1):

Try a single line port specification without spaces, like such:

```
$ cat ports.list
21-23,25
$
```

That works as expected:

```
$ nmap -p `cat ports.list` host.example.com

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-25 15:07 UTC
Nmap scan report for host.example.com (192.168.1.17)
Host is up (0.00089s latency).

PORT   STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp closed ftp
22/tcp open   ssh
23/tcp closed telnet
25/tcp open   smtp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
$
```

Note that in the answer you reference, he used 'tr' to translate one-port-per-line into single-line-comma-delimited.